# How to add iAd in SpriteKit and deactivate it when a scene changes?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

In my game file `GameScene`, I wrote code for iAd to be displayed there.

```
func addiAd(){
    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true
    bannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(bannerView.frame, 0.0, 0.0)
    bannerView.center = CGPointMake(bannerView.center.x,  
    (view?.bounds.size.height)! - bannerView.frame.size.height/2)
    view!.addSubview(bannerView)
    print("iAd is working")
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView.hidden = true
}
```

Well, it first looks like it works, but not perfectly because when a scene has transitioned to another game scene file called `GameOverScene`, my `bannerView` does not disappear and stays where it appeared forever until the run is over. I want to deactivate this. Is my code wrong written above? In my source code, in total, I want two `adBanner` views in `GameScene` and `GameOverScene` respectively. My assumption for the error is that I did not write those code in GameViewController, but I am unsure about it. Could you show me how to implement it and explain me where it has to be written?

Comment: just so you know, Apple is closing the iAd network June 30th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iAd delegate methods you could change the `alpha` properties of your banner. For example:

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.alpha = 1.0
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView.alpha = 0.0
}
```

And then when you're changing scenes or want to make sure that the iAd banner does not appear you could set its `hidden` property. For example:

```
func hideBanner() {
    // Call whenever you don't want the ADBannerView to be on screen
    bannerView.hidden = true
}

func showBanner() {
    // Call when you want the ADBannerView to be on screen
    bannerView.hidden = false
}
```

This would require you to update your `addiAd` function also: Change `bannerView.hidden = true` to `bannerView.alpha = 0.0`.

And finally you shouldn't be removing the iAd banner from the Superview here:

```
func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could I ask one more question? It would be nicer to have a x button to delete the bannerView when its shown. Is there any easy code to implement to do that?

Comment: @ryohei Create a custom UIButton for your close button and position it at the corner of your ADBannerView. Then have the UIButton call the hideBanner func when it is tapped.

Comment: Ah! Cool! Thought there was some built-in code for that! Just UIButton to add. I see. Thanks for your answer :)